# How do I call Coffeescript templates in a Javascript ERB template in a jquery_ujs response?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ujs

I am using [Coffeescript template](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) in my Rails 3.1 app, so in my app/assets/javascripts/post.js.coffee file, I have something like:

```
$('#post').html JST['templates/posts/show'] post: post
```

where post is a JSON object. The template is in app/assets/javascripts/templates/posts/show

Now I am also using jquery_ujs to respond to PostsController#create and want to use app/views/posts/show.js.erb to render a response. In show.js.erb, I want to use the template from above. How would I go about doing that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like https://github.com/markbates/coffeebeans might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use power of Rails templates.
If you rename your respond file as show.js.coffee.erb (or show.coffee.erb - don't remember) you than rails template engine generates for you .erb code, after that it will translate coffee to js, and only after that your client will gain the response text.

With .erb it works fine. With .haml I have some problems...